# CORS ASP.NET webservice from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, cors

I'm trying to figure out how to make a regular html page (with javascript) get data from a WebService which I created in Visual Studio using Asp.Net. My final project is going to have the WebService hosted in one domain and the results will need to be received by the html page in another domain.

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to set up the webservice such that my page can talk to it.

I've been trying to follow:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server

[Ajax Without JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188488/ajax-without-jquery)

and the video here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet

but I can't seem to work out the kinks. When I try to load the page using Firefox nothing is returned. I'm almost positive that the problem has to do with the URL I'm trying to use, but I don't know enough to figure out what it should be.

What is the best way to get the return value from the function HelloWorld2 using javascript?

Thanks in advance.

WebService

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace StoneSoupMockup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://SomeDumbUniqueID.org/", Description="This is a sample service for Stone Soup.", Name="MyService")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld2(string something)
        {
            return "Hello " + something;
        }
    }
}
```

I added access control headers to the httpProtocol in the web.config of my web services project like this

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

JavaScript:

```
//WebServices.js
function myAjax() {
     var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     //I'm really not sure about this URL. This is what Visual Studio has for the 
     //URL when I test my app
     var url="http://localhost:62033/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld2";
     //var parameters = "first=barack&last=obama";
     var parameters = "something=timmy"
     xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

     //Black magic paragraph
     xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
     xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById('ajaxDump').innerHTML+=xmlHttp.responseText+"<br />";
      }
     }

     xmlHttp.send(parameters);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <script src="WebServices.js" type='text/javascript'></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="resultdiv"></div>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        myAjax();   
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CORS library as part of your service. If you need it now, then look into the Thinktecture IdentityModel library:

http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

Otherwise wait for the next release of WebAPI:

http://brockallen.com/2013/03/13/cors-open-source-contribution-to-asp-net-and-system-web-cors/

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Also, congrats on your contribution to ASP.net! That's no small feat! Let me check it out and I'll upvote your answer once I'm able to make it work.

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long for me to get back to you on this. (I've been away from work for a while.)

Somehow that whole setup seems excessive. If all I'm attempting is to call a web service method and do something with the result using javascript, I don't understand why all the server side code is required. I think I should submit a new question that more adequately describes my problem.

Comment: Turns out I had multiple problems. The biggest was as Brock suggested, that my web service wasn't allowing Cross Origin requests. I used the WebAPI as Brock suggested which required upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 to use .Net 4.5. Kind of irritated at that. The second issue was that when I was debugging on my local machine using Firefox 17 the origin was null. I solved this problem by spoofing the origin using HttpFox plugin.