# JavaScript communicate with web Service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, service, cross-domain

i have a JS project that tries to send arguments to asp.net web service
the web service is on IIS server.
this is my JS function:

```
function call_Ajax(func, param, callback) {


    var pageUrl ="http://XXXXX.com/gdmService/LoggerService.asmx/"+ func;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "",
        data: param,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: eval(callback),
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }

    });
}
```

if i run this function from a page on the same project as the Service it working great.
(the pageUrl is different it's just the name of the service cuz' it on the same solution)
but when i'm trying to use this function form a different page i'm getting an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://XXXX.com/gdmService/LoggerService.asmx/Write2DB. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://XXXX.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

(i tried also with http)

if i try to copy and paste the link to the browser the error is:

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/Write2DB'.
```

i read about it and some people said that it's a cross domain problem (most of the info i found was with JS to PHP)

how can i fix it?

on the service all the method are `[Web Methods]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CORS ASP.NET webservice from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097587/cors-asp-net-webservice-from-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Change your dataType to be "jsonp".

Comment: The person asking the question is attempting to make a POST request,  JSONP only works for GET requests.