# jQuery.ajax Content from an end point which responds differently depending on the hash value in the url

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hash, anchor

Main question: How do I retrieve content with a url like "http://www.example.com/index.html#foo" via jQuery.ajax()?

Note: The following works for scripts, which is what I was originally requesting:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'http://www.example.com/script.js#foo';
$('head').append(script);
```

And you can build your own request in the plain old ajax way using [the method found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188488/ajax-without-jquery):

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="http://www.example.com/index.html#foo";
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);

xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 0);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
         alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
     }
}

xmlHttp.send();
```

However, this just seems like something jQuery.ajax should support.

As for jQuery, I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/index.html#foo',
    cache: true
});
```

However, the request that is actually made is to "http://www.example.com/index.html". If I have no control over the end point I'm working with, and it responds with completely different content if "#foo" is not in the url, this is bad.

Based on an answer to another question on SO, I tried the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/index.html',
    cache: true,
    data: {
        '': '#foo'
    }
});
```

However, the url that is requested is then "http://www.example.com/index.html?=#foo" which adds the equals sign and the ? for the query string (things I don't want).

Another question indicated that you can encode the url and then decode it in the beforeSend function, but I'm not sure what I can do to modify the request url in that location.

Since I already have a work around, this question is academic rather than an *incredibly important time sensitive end of the world question*, but I'm still curious. I bet I'm missing something dumb.

Unfortunately I lost my other SO question references while writing this up. So apologies for that.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Tried using `$.getScript()` ?

Comment: $.getScript() is just a wrapper on $.ajax. So it strips the hash as well. Thanks though.

Comment: Looks like this is in the works for the next version of jQuery!
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1732
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/2721

Comment: The fix for this bug was introduced in jQuery 3.0. Hooray! http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-hash-in-a-url-is-preserved-in-a-jquery-ajax-call